# Set maximum time of UIDatePicker in countDownTimer mode

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I am new to swift and I'm trying to have a picker to select the frequency of notifications. I want to set the max amount the user can pick to be 2 hours, but what I'm doing is not working anyone knows if this is possible?

This is what i have done:

```
let minutePicker = UIDatePicker()
minutePicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
minutePicker.minuteInterval = 10 //sets the interval of minutes.
minutePicker.countDownDuration = 30*60 //set starting value.
minutePicker.maximumDate = Date(timeInterval: 60*60*2, since: Date())
```

Comment: Why don't you use a UIPickerView?

Comment: I assumed it would be better to use the UIDatePicker in a countDownTimer, and i just wanted to know if that was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
   let minutePicker = UIDatePicker()
    minutePicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
    minutePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(respondToChanges(picker:)), for: .valueChanged)
    minutePicker.minuteInterval = 10

    var components = DateComponents()
    components.minute = 30
    let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
    minutePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
```

Then you have to create a respondToChanges method. A possible implementation would look like this:

```
@objc
func respondToChanges(picker: UIDatePicker) {
    if (picker.countDownDuration > 7200) { //countDownDuration has to be in seconds
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = 2
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
        picker.setDate(date, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The documentation says: "The minimum and maximum dates are ignored in the countdown-timer mode". So with my solution you set the time manually back to 2 hours, each time the user select more than 2 hours.

Comment: This works but i was thinking if it's possible to remove the options that are larger than 2 hours?